# Non builtin command and $PATH

Tags: linux, file, path, executable

At the beginging i have to mention that im complete newbie in linux.
I have to show that when you use non builtin command such as `cat`, linux is searching in `$PATH` for an executable file and after it finds one, it won't search any further. Is there any way of doing that NOT by  `cp` other command and changing it name or making completely new script with same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strace` to inspect system calls made by a process.

```
 $ strace bash -c 'cat /dev/null' 2>&1 | grep cat
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "cat /dev/null"], 0x7ffcc25e5ab0 /* 91 vars */) = 0
stat("/usr/local/bin/cat", 0x7fff874b7150) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/cat", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=39112, ...}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/cat", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=39112, ...}, 0) = 0
access("/usr/bin/cat", X_OK)            = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/cat", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=39112, ...}, 0) = 0
access("/usr/bin/cat", R_OK)            = 0
stat("/usr/bin/cat", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=39112, ...}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/cat", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=39112, ...}, 0) = 0
access("/usr/bin/cat", X_OK)            = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/cat", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=39112, ...}, 0) = 0
access("/usr/bin/cat", R_OK)            = 0
execve("/usr/bin/cat", ["cat", "/dev/null"], 0x561cafdde4f0 /* 91 vars */) = 0
```

In my case, `bash` tried to first `/usr/local/bin/cat`, then opened `/usr/bin/cat`.